# AppStore Review Crash logs

Tags: swift, app-store

I submitted An app to AppStore. but its being rejected claiming it crashes on launch but it works fine on my device and simulators.
they send the crash logs to troubleshooting.

[Crash Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h38MaUkUSvp8xIVdjaPdmacKPGJP5Kjd)

Answer (score 1):

Your application was killed by iOS because it took too long to launch (19 seconds, if we read the crash files).

I wouldn't know to say why it takes that long to launch, though. What is your app doing on launch? More data would be appreciated to help.

Comment: In the appdelegete there are some functions to create a sql database at first launch and declations of global variables